# How to Convert text input to element input in javascript (js)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

i want get row in datatable js each row content input['checkbox'], i can get input checkbox but it is text, i can't any operation like normal input example (attr, value, etc). 
how to convert to normal element ?

`<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="check_4">
Create:296 <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="check_1">
Create:296 <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="check_2">
Create:296 <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="check_3">`

> get each row by code

```
var table = $('#table_id').DataTable();
        var data = table.rows().data();
        data.each(function (value, index) {
            const input = value[0];
            console.log(input.at);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your can try this:

```
        var table = $('#table_id').DataTable();
        var data = table.rows().data();
        data.each(function (value, index) {
            const input = value[1];
            var el = $.parseHTML(input)
            console.log(el);
        });
```

Comment: thanks this code work but i have a new problem :( , 
i want get all check box is checked in datatable js but only get checkbox chekck show, why ?

Comment: try using table.rows({ selected: true }).data();

Answer (score 0):

im not sure i correct understood your problem,but if yes close yours all inputs in one class(name: myInputCollection). Than you can try to getElementsByClassName("myInputCollection"). Than try to iterate by its child elements. all of them should be Yours input checkbox elements.
Or just try to go with GetElementsByClassName("form-control"), result ll be array of Your   then just iterate by them.